# Find the ratio of the area $EDPQ$ to the area of ABC

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, ratio

In triangle $ABC$,points $E$ and $D$ are on side $AC$ and point $F$ is on side $BC$ such that AE=ED=DC and $BF:FC$ =2:3. $AF$ intersects $BD$ and $BE$ at points $P$ and $Q$, respectively. Find the ratio of the area $EDPQ$ to the area of $ABC$

*taken from the 2017 IMC held in India*

I assumed ABD was equilateral so that the area of ABE would be equal to BED but didn’t gain anything from that

Comment: Are you familiar with using mass points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k\in DC$ such that $FK||BD$.

Thus, $DK:KC=2:3.$

Let $DC=5x$.

Thus, $DK=2x$ and $AD=10x$, which gives
$$\frac{AP}{PF}=\frac{AD}{DK}=\frac{10x}{2x}=5.$$
Similarly, let $M\in EC$ such that $FM||BE.$

Thus, $EM:MC=2:3,$ which gives $EM=4x$ and
$$\frac{AQ}{QF}=\frac{AE}{EM}=\frac{5x}{4x}=\frac{5}{4}.$$
From here we obtain:
$$AQ:QP:PF=10:5:3.$$
Now, $$S_{\Delta BPQ}=\frac{5}{18}S_{\Delta ABF}=\frac{5}{18}\cdot\frac{2}{5}S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{1}{9}S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{1}{3}S_{\Delta BED},$$
which gives
$$S_{EDPQ}=\frac{2}{3}S_{\Delta BED}=\frac{2}{9}S_{\Delta ABC}$$ and we are done!